# Select rows that match exact value set from view

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a view, `shipping`, which contains 2 columns: `pack list (PL)` and `orders`.

I want to select all the `pack list` that contain *exactly* the `orders` in a specific set.

Constraints:

- An order can have multiple pack lists and a pack list can have multiple orders.
- This is a view, so repeated rows are possible.

Sample:

```sql
+----+--------+
| PL | orders |
+----+--------+
|  1 |   a    |
+----+--------+
|  1 |   b    |
+----+--------+
|  1 |   c    |
+----+--------+
|  2 |   c    |
+----+--------+
|  2 |   c    |
+----+--------+
|  3 |   a    |
+----+--------+
|  3 |   c    |
+----+--------+
|  4 |   a    |
+----+--------+
|  4 |   b    |
+----+--------+
|  5 |   a    |
+----+--------+
|  5 |   c    |
+----+--------+
|  5 |   c    |
+----+--------+
```

I want the `PL` that have exactly the orders `a` and `c` -> `3` and `5`.

I've come to this solution, which is working:

```sql
SELECT PL FROM shipping WHERE PL NOT IN
  (SELECT PL FROM shipping WHERE orders NOT IN('a','c'))
GROUP BY PL HAVING count(DISTINCT orders) = 2;
```

but I think that something cleaner can be done, for example not relying on the number of orders in the set, or maybe using the [ROLLUP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) function.

I've done a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3b848) for testing purposes, here I make a table and not a view adding an auto increment ID as `primary key` (but for some reason auto increment doesn't work, maybe I'm missing some syntax).

Are there any other approaches to construct this query?

Comment: For a start your solution as it is,will NOT work.

Comment: @Mihai can you explain why with a counter example? Also, have you tried it in the SQL Fiddle?

Comment: You have hAVING before GROUP BY,its viceversa.

Comment: @Mihai whoops, that's a typo. Thanks for noticing! Editing.

Comment: @Strawberry It is referred to the SQL Fiddle ddl... I didn't struggle to understand and try to build a perfect ddl, it's just for test. This is totally unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines:

```
SELECT PL 
FROM shipping 
GROUP BY PL
HAVING count(DISTINCT orders) = 2
  AND count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN orders IN('a','c') THEN orders ELSE NULL END) = 2
```

Comment: You also are using the number of orders to fetch the data, which I wanted not to do, but I think I cannot get rid of it. I think now its just a matter of execution time and complexity...

Comment: Alternatively you can INNER / LEFT join shipping table three times to itself, not sure if that will be better.

Comment: If you are worried about performance, it does not matter how you do it, you will need a full table scan. `GROUP BY` + `HAVING` are likely to beat any other solution. If you test it against other options, please share results.